# How to validate an object with a key inside it in Yup Validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

This is a snippet in my React application using Formik.

My initial value is

```
initialValues: {
    country: { label: '', value: '' }
}
```

My field input is `country` which is a `Select` option and its value when selected will be as

```
country: { label: 'India', value: 'India' }
```

My required `error` object when a `country` is not selected should be

```
{ country: "Please select a country" }
```

How can I add a yup validation to get my required error when a country is not selected, or in other means when `country.value === ''`?

I wrote a validation like this

```
country: yup.object().shape({
        value: yup
            .string()
            .label('Country')
            .required("Please select a country"),
})
```

which is wrong and this gives the error object as `country: { value: "Please select a country" }` which is not as my requirement.

What changes should I do here?

Answer (score 0):

The `value: ''` is considered a missing value for strings, so most validations besides `.required()` ignore it. In this case, you can either:

- Set a default country value
- Or remove the `.required()` rule.

Comment: I found the answer is updated as the answer for this question

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer as follows.

```
country: yup
        .object()
        .test(
          'country', 
          'Please select Country', 
          val => !val.value ? false : true,
        )
```

This will check if `value` key inside the `country` object and return `false` if empty and the given error will be assigned directly to the `country` object as required.

Answer (score 0):

```
country: Yup.object()
  .shape({
    label: Yup.string().ensure().required(),
    value: Yup.string().ensure().required(),
  })
  .required("Country cannot be empty")
  .nullable()
```

In my case, initial value of the country is null, and then it receives an object when the change is triggered.